# Laravel Blade if/else directive change status color

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, tailwind-css

I am getting draft post status alone, I have a post with a publish & decline status, but only the draft status is showing in my if/else statement.

```
@if ($post->status == 'draft')
    <span class="px-4 font-bold text-red-400 border-2 border-red-400 rounded-full">
        {{ $post->status }}
    </span>
@elseif($post->status == 'publish')
    <span class="px-4 font-bold text-green-400 border-2 border-green-400 rounded-full">
        {{ $post->status }}
    </span>
@elseif($post->status == 'decline')
    <span class="px-4 font-bold text-red-400 border-2 border-red-400 rounded-full">
        Decline
    </span>
@endif
```

Comment: Did you try adding a space between @elseif and the condition ?

Comment: yes I did but I don't know why it's not working